# The action of $GL(\mathbb{R}^{n})\otimes GL(\mathbb{R}^{m})$ on $\mathbb{R}P^{(mn-1)}$

Tags: matrices, ds.dynamical-systems, group-actions

Motivated by the [following RG question](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_know_that_it_is_possible_to_add_a_row_to_set_of_convex_and_compact_full_rank_matrices_such_that_rank_of_any_matrix_increases) we ask a related question as follows:

We identify $\mathbb{R}^{n} \otimes \mathbb{R}^{m}$  with $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$. We define $GL(\mathbb{R}^{n})\otimes GL(\mathbb{R}^{m})$ as  a  subgroup of $GL(\mathbb{R}^{n} \otimes \mathbb{R}^{m})$ which consist  simple tensors $T\otimes S\;\; \text{where}\;\;T\in GL(\mathbb{R}^{n}),\;S\in GL(\mathbb{R}^{m})$.

> Is the action of  $GL(\mathbb{R}^{n})\otimes GL(\mathbb{R}^{m})$ on $\mathbb{R}P^{(mn-1)}$ a transitive action? If not, what is the topological description of the quotion $\mathbb{R}P^{(mn-1)}/GL(\mathbb{R}^{n})\otimes GL(\mathbb{R}^{m})$?

The above action is the restriction of the natural action of $GL(\mathbb{R}^{n} \otimes \mathbb{R}^{m})$

**Note:** "$GL(\mathbb{R}^{n})\otimes GL(\mathbb{R}^{m})$" is just  a  notation so we do not confuse it with the tensor product of two groups or some thing else.  After that I post this question, I heard from Todd Trimble that this group is isomorphic to $\frac{GL(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \times GL(\mathbb{R}^{m})} {\mathbb{R}^{*}}$ with obvious action $\lambda.(A,B)=(\lambda A, \lambda^{-1}B)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the evident isomorphism of $\mathbb R^m\otimes \mathbb R^n$ with $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$, the orbits of the action of $Gl(\mathbb R^m)\otimes Gl(\mathbb R^n)$ corresponds to orbits of the action of $Gl(\mathbb R^m)\times Gl(\mathbb R^n)$ on  $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$ by 
left and right multiplication:
$$(A,B)\cdot X = AXB^t.$$

And the orbit of an element in this action is determined only by its rank. It's because for a matrix $X\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$ its orbit under right multiplication is only determined by  span of its column vectors, and two subspaces of $\mathbb R^m$ of the same dimension are conjugate under automorphisms  of $\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does the orbits determined  ONLY  by rank? If so, is the quotion space a finite discrete space? Is not this strange?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Yes, I think it's only determined by rank and so the quotient is a finite set of size $min(m,n)+1$ but its topology is not discrete.

Comment: because the rank is upper semi continuous?

Comment: Are there some other natural  examples that a lie group act on a compact connected manifold but the quotien is  a finite non Haussdorfn space?

Comment: @Ali Yes, indeed the closed sets are exactly the orbits of matrices with an upper bound on rank. For the second question, I think $(\mathbb C^*)^n$ action on toric varieties provide a large set of examples.

Comment: what is the structure of the Lie algebra of this Lie group?